# Нет доступ к некоторым запросам после авторизации VK

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть Spring Boot Web приложение которое использует Java VK SDK. Авторизация в приложение происходит по клику на ссылку:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6724221&.....
```

После того как пользователь разрешил приложению использовать его данные на я получаю примерно такой ответ:

```
https://my.server-host.net/callbacks/vk?code=code_value
```

Этот redirect_url указан в настройках приложения: Доверенный redirect URI, Адрес сайта и Базовый домен.

На сервере использую полученный код для получения access_token  используя Java SDK.

С полученным токеном я не могу создать группу или событие на стороне сервера, получаю ошибку 15.

Как я могу получить токен для работы c SDK на серверной стороне с запрашиваемым доступом?

Comment: А вы права `groups` прописали в первом запросе, при генерации токена?

Comment: Да, в sсope я указывають `groups`

Comment: Может быть проблема в том что ВК требует токен получен в Standalone-приложении через Implicit Flow для создание группы, а Java SDK делает авторизацию через Authorization Code Flow?

Comment: возможно и такое

Comment: @Let'ssayPie как же тогда исправить проблему?